# AutoHotKey: Run Power BI in Background

Tags: autohotkey

I am looking to run the following script behind the scenes while I work on other stuff.

I know that the click should be converted to ClickSend and the Sends should be Controlsend, but how do I move the Run command to the background as well?

```
Run C:\Users\rob\OneDrive\Pictures\testing.pbix
sleep 15000
MouseClick, left, 105,  143
sleep 5000
MouseClick, left, 105, 750
sleep 5000
MouseClick, left, 600, 430
sleep 10000
send {ctrl down}{shift down}{s down}
sleep 5000
send {ctrl up}{shift up}{s up}
sleep 5000
send {enter down}
send {enter up}
sleep 2000
send {enter down}
send {enter up}
sleep 2000
send {left down}
send {left up}
sleep 2000
send {enter down}
send {enter up}
```

Comment: I don't really get the question. How could the Run command could be anywhere else but "in the background". The Run command just runs something whenever you specify it to run something.

Comment: That would directly have to do with what program is opening .pbix files by default on your computer. Could you please tell us which program is opening it?

Comment: Power BI Desktop opens the file. Currently, when I run this script, a new window of Power BI pops up and opens the 'testing.pbix' file. Then the rest of the program runs based on that open window. What I am looking to do is move that entire process to the background

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ClickSend` nor `ControlSend` without a window. I would suggest running the program with `Run`, using [`WinWait`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm) to wait for the window open and then hide it using [`WinHide`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinHide.htm). `ClickSend` and `ControlSend` should work on hidden windows.